# Selecting Second row if available if not first in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like below:

[image]

i want to Select Operator entry that corresponds to RowNumber 2 of InstanceNumber 1 and rownumber 1 of other instances. This is one example where only instancenumber 1 has two rownumber's but I want to able to pick last rownumber of each intances. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(rownumber) over (partition by instancenumber) as maxrn
      from t
     ) t
where rownumber = maxrn;
```

That said, if you have the right indexes, the following might be a tad faster:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.rownumber = (select max(t2.rownumber) from t t2 where t2.instancenumber = t.instancenumber);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The Second query worked however the first one did not. I wrote the first query like so:

Select t.OperatorEntry from (Select OperatorEntry, max(rownumber) over (partition by instancenumber) as maxrn from cteTempTable) t where RowNumber = maxrn